# Remover associação em relação Many to Many

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Tenho um relacionamento `@manytomany` unidirecional e preciso remover essa associação de acordo com algum critério mas não queria ter que navegar por todos os objetos da coleção para remover um-a-um.

Pensei em um `JQPL` "`delete from ...`" mas não sei como fazer isso.

Obs:

- Nenhum dos objetos serão excluídos, apenas a associação entre eles.
- Trabalho com MultiTenant com múltiplos Databases, onde cada cliente possui seu próprio banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível executar um `delete` ou mesmo `update` através de JPQL através do método `createQuery` do `EntityManager`.

Exemplo ([fonte](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete)):

```java
Query query = em.createQuery(
    "DELETE FROM EntidadeAssociacao t WHERE t.idOrigem = :idOrigem and t.idDestino = :idDestino");
int deletedCount = query
    .setParameter("idOrigem", 1)
    .setParameter("idDestino", 2)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Entretanto, é importante lembrar que qualquer comando dessa natureza ou via *native query* (consulta nativa) afeta diretamente a base, portanto pode as entidades no contexto do JPA não refletirão a alteração imediatamente.

Se necessário, use o método `entityManager.refresh()` para atualizar as entidades.

Comment: No caso "TabelaAssociacao" é o nome da tabela no banco de dados? Porque eu trabalho com MultiTenant com multiplos databases (cada cliente possui seu próprio banco de dados).

Comment: @utluiz sua resposta funciona, mas é necessário tomar cuidado com as entidades que ficarão *detachadas* da sessão.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Na verdade, ali vai o nome da classe. Ficou ruim o exemplo. Sorry :S

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Sim, tomar cuidado para não tentar reusar os objetos que foram removidos do banco é o mínimo de cuidado que o desenvolvedor precisa ter.

Comment: Perai @utluiz, deixa eu ver se entendi... para sua dica funcionar eu devo criar uma nova classe/entidade que representará a tabela de associação? Dessa forma eu acho que resolve meu problema.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Sim, no exemplo preciso ter uma classe. Mas mesmo que não tenha pode usar o método `createNativeQuery` para acessar diretamente a tabela. Desculpe não ter explicado mais em detalhes, mas tá meio difícil essa semana.

Comment: @utluiz Como faço pra deletar a associação sem ela estar mapeada?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Se for apenas um item você pode excluir numa das pontas, isto é, numa das entidades onde o relacionamento está mapeado. Ou, como mencionei acima, use uma query nativa.

Comment: @utluiz Tentei o metodo que você mencionou, porém tenho um erro falando que minha entidade não está mapeada. Eu queria excluir apenas o item da relação e manter as outras pontas

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Impossível ajudar assim. Crie uma nova pergunta é coloque os detalhes das suas classes.

Comment: @utluiz http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134183/excluir-entidade-criada-de-uma-rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o-manytomany

Answer (score 2):

Para excluir apenas a associação é simples. Suponha o cenário abaixo:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) 
private List<Foo> foos;
```

Se você remover um elemento de *foos* e salvar a entidade você vai excluir o registro na tabela de join.

**EDIT**

Eu particularmente não gosto de fugir do contexto ORM. Então se percorrer a lista e excluir os elementos um a um é um fardo eu posso dar duas alternativas:

1. Se você puder usar java 8, use um lamda. Com um único comando você percorre toda a lista e remove o que você quer.
2. Caso o Java 8 não seja uma solução, use a resposta do utluiz. Ela lhe atende.

**Conforme eu lhe falei nos comentários:** Este tipo de abordagem que você procura não é legal pois cria a necessidade de realizar um delete e depois um refresh para atualizar toda a sua sessão *(o que no fim será menos performático)*, além de deixar seu sistema passível a erro, pois estará lidando com objetos *detachados* que podem acidentalmente serem *retachados*, tornando seu sistema inconsistente.

Percorrer a lista, excluir os elementos e depois salvar o objeto é menos custoso na maioria dos casos, pois você está trabalhando *in-memory* na maior parte do tempo, e mais robusto por não estar saindo do contexto ORM.

Então se for trabalhar de uma forma diferente dessa eu sugiro que avalie se o JDBC não lhe atenderá melhor.

Comment: O problema é que eu não vou excluir nenhum dos dois objetos, quero somente desvincula-los.

Comment: @NilsonUehara editei minha resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Sim, é isso que eu já faço agora. Eu queria evitar ter que iterar todas as coleções para remover um por um. Eu queria fazer algo do tipo: delete from Ligacao where B.id=1, assim todos os objetos que estiverem relacionados a B teriam sua ligação excluída.

Comment: @NilsonUehara você tem que entender que isso não é SQL. Usar esse tipo de abordagem pode deixar seu entity manager confuso e causar inconsistências, se for para trabalhar desse jeito eu sugiro que use jdbc. Agora a resposta do utluiz faz o que você quer.

Comment: Edgar, sua resposta é a resposta correta do ponto de vista do JPA. O problema é que essa solução é sub-ótima, porque o JPA é sub-ótimo para esse tipo de tarefa. Aliás, todos esses problemas tem me feito pensar 500 vezes antes de usar JPA num projeto. JdbcTemplate tem me dado muito menos dor de cabeça em projetos que tem nível de complexidade no mínimo moderado.

Comment: @utluiz eu concordo em parte com você. Não existe bala de prata, isso é fato. Agora muitas pessoas utilizam a tecnologia de forma que não deve ser usada, isso faz criar pensamentos como o que você expressou, que de certa forma é justo. O que usuário quer com esta pergunta é fazer um *by-pass* na framework, coisa que não deve ser feita. Existe um ditado que diz: *Poder fazer algo não significa que você deva faze-lo*.