# Excluir entidade criada de uma relação ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Tenho uma relação `ManyToMany` entre `users` e `profiles` mapeadas com `Hibernate`:

**user:**

```
id
name
```

**profile:**

```
id
profile_name
```

**user_profile:**

```
user_id
profile_id
```

---

O mapeamento é feito da seguinte forma:

**User:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Profile**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "profiles")
private List<User> users= new ArrayList<>();
```

Até aqui está tranquilo, todas as entidades são criadas no banco e já tenho alguns dados persistidos nelas.

Atualmente faço o método excluir dessa forma:

```
public void excluir(T entity) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(entity);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (transacao != null)
                transacao.rollback();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

> Como faço pra excluir um item da relação `user_profile`? Não quero
>   excluir o `User` e nem o `Profile`, apenas um item da relação entre os dois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que se você adicionar um cascade na anotação ManyToMany já resolveria a questão, da uma olhada neste [tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

`@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`

**[EDIT]**

Um exemplo de um projeto que tenho aqui e funciona esta mapeada a relação `@ManyToMany` da seguinte maneira (unidirecional):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinTable(name = "tabelarelacional", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidadeforte"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_entidadefraca")) 
private Set<EntidadeFraca> listaEntidadeFraca;
```

Dessa forma basta apenas remover os objetos da lista de `listaEntidadeFraca` da EntidadeForte que não pertencem mais a ela e fazer o update da EntidadeForte.

Com isso as linhas criadas na tabela de ligação também serão removidas.

**Exemplo:** `entidadeForte = {id:1, listaEntidadeFraca:[ entidadeFraca1, entidadeFraca2]}`

**Removendo:** `entidadeForte = {id:1, listaEntidadeFraca:[ entidadeFraca1]}`

**Update**: `session.merge(entidadeForte);`